# MySql 8.0 compiled from source

Tags: mysql

I compiled mysql 8 from source and imported a mysqldump file with all tables. This messed up the mysql.infoschema user its missing.

When i recreate it i get a storage engine myisam does not support tables;

running show databases gives my the missing infoschema user.

Assuming i just messed everything up with the import i move the datadir to a datadir.bak. Mysql still starts and all the databases are there use database command works the same errors occur. I have searched everywhere for another copy of the data dir that might have been created but i can't find anything. I use the variables in mysql and it points to the datadir that i created with initialize after moving the old datadir.

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "%dir";

```
+-----------------------------+----------------------------------+
| Variable_name               | Value                            |
+-----------------------------+----------------------------------+
| basedir                     | /usr/local/mysql/                |
| character_sets_dir          | /usr/local/mysql/share/charsets/ |
| datadir                     | /usr/local/mysql/data/           |
| innodb_data_home_dir        |                                  |
| innodb_doublewrite_dir      |                                  |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir   | ./                               |
| innodb_temp_tablespaces_dir | ./#innodb_temp/                  |
| innodb_tmpdir               |                                  |
| lc_messages_dir             | /usr/local/mysql/share/          |
| plugin_dir                  | /usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin/     |
| replica_load_tmpdir         | /tmp                             |
| slave_load_tmpdir           | /tmp                             |
| tmpdir                      | /tmp                             |
+-----------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

root@tbred2:/usr/local/mysql/lib# ls -lah /usr/local/mysql/data|grep tbred
root@tbred2:/usr/local/mysql/lib#

mysql> use tbred; <-- Does not exist in data directory
Database changed
mysql> select @@datadir;

```
    +------------------------+
    | @@datadir              |
    +------------------------+
    | /usr/local/mysql/data/ |
    +------------------------+
```

Comment: What is your question?  This seems more for the dba Stack Exchange rather than Stack Overflow.